# Express Cannot GET /images

Tags: javascript, express, get

I'm using Express and for some reason, when using JavaScript I can access images but whenever I try and directly implement the image route to the src such as

```
<img src="images/background.png">
```

The localhost determines that it is unable to get the image.

I'm pointing a static to a `/public` route in the `server.js` file which is why it is baffling me as to why it can receive some images but not all?

This is my current line that determines the public route.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a absolute path definition:

```
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Your directroy structure should look like this:

```
 server.js -> "where app.use(express.static()) is defined"
 ---| public
 -------| images
 -----------| background.png
```

Comment: I get an error when running 'node server.js' which states that path is not defined.

Comment: @cmiotk Updated, you need to inject path.

Comment: Still getting the same issues `GET http://localhost:3000/images/background.png 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Mhm, crazy. It does work over here. Are you sure images/background.png exists and is readable? Please check for capital characters (case sensitive).

Comment: I found the issue, I have no idea as to why it was doing it. When I exported the image from photoshop, although it was a `.png` and exported as a `.png` the actual file extension wasn't on the image for whatever reason. Adding the `.png` to `background.png` seemed to have fixed the problem. Extremely odd though! However, I did need the lines of code that you give me!

Comment: Glad to help ya =)

Comment: Doesn't works for me

Answer (score -1):

I couldnt GET my png because there were some invisible characters in the name of the file.
Make sure there are no special characters in the file name, you can try renaming it.